# Why won't my background image show?

Tags: html, css, image, header

What's the reason my header image won't show?
(any advice for the future will be appreciated!)

---

Below you'll see my current syntax.
I wanted to add a jsfiddle link, but since everything refers to images I have on my computer, I thought it would be easier to upload my entire folder instead.
[HERE](https://www.sendspace.com/file/qzfzzs) is the link to that

---

html

```
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <link href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">    
        <div id="header"></div><!-- end header -->

        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php"><img border="0" id="homebutton" alt="" src="img/home button.png" width="145px" height="auto"></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php"><img border="0" id="aboutbutton" alt="" src="img/about button.png" width="145px" height="auto"></a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.php"><img border="0" id="gallerybutton" alt="" src="img/gallery button.png" width="145px" height="auto"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php"><img border="0" id="contactbutton" alt="" src="img/contact button.png" width="145px" height="auto"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end menu -->

        <div id="content"></div><!-- einde content -->      
    </div><!-- end container -->    
</body>
```

css

```
#container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1300px;
}

#header {
    background-image: url("img/header.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1300px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 275px;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#menu ul li  {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: have you pressed f12 and gone into elements to see if its in the DOM ?

Comment: Try setting some height to the header, say `height: 200px;`

Comment: Is your CSS in another folder? Because if it's, you should add `url("../path/image.png")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actual `height` is `0px`, so you can't see it.
You need to write a size too, like `height: 10px`; or `min-height: 10px`.

Answer (score 3):

That is because in the header, you are only setting `max-height` and the `height` to `auto`, you should include a `min-height` for it to show.

Comment: Thank you! (and everyone else)
Setting a min-height did it for me :)

Answer (score 3):

try changing `max-height: 275px;` to `min-height:275px;`

the `div` has no contents so defaults to being `0px` high

Answer (score 2):

You used the image as a background but background of what? (I mean there is no size of the header `div` so the background cannot be displayed)

You have to increase the size (`width`/`height`) of the   `<div id="header"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

On your `#header`, change

```
 height:auto;
```

to something like

```
height: 200px; //or whatever the height of your img is
```

The problem here is that your `div` defaults to `height: 0px;` and therefore there's no room for your image to show.

Alternatively, you need to at least set a `min-height` on the div so the image can show.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set an height to your `header`. As you set the `max-height` you are saying the height cannot pass that number, but your header is empty, so the height will be 0.

Second, be careful with paths. May in your HTML the path was `img/image.png`, but your css file is in a folder called `styles`. If that's your case, remember to add the relative path to the image from the styles folder, `background-image: url("../relative/path/to/image.png");`

Answer (score 0):

your problem is css, `#header` styles. Please try `width:100px` instead of  `width:auto`. (100px is example). This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML file is in root, the syntax would be ok at the image, but else it could be instead of: 
`background-image: url("img/header.png");` 
`background-image: url("/img/header.png");` (note the "/" at the url)
 Or the name of the image. Or the extension.